# included numbers in numpy arange

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I hope to get a simple decimal range by numpy.arange .
But, my code outputs unexpected result and size.
My snippet shown below.

```
len(arange(0.60,0.70,0.01))
```

it returns size 10 ndarray object

```
array([0.60, ... ,0.69])
```

And, the max value is changed

```
len(arange(0.60,0.80,0.01))

array([0.60, ... , 0.79, 0.80])
```

I expected it will also return size 20 one.

array([0.60, ... , 0.79])

But, the size is 21 and 0.80 is included.
Could you explain Why is this? and What is the difference between two ranges?

Python : 3.5.2
numpy : 1.10.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is writen in [numpy.arange documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html),

"When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not be consistent. It is better to use `linspace` for these cases."

Note that `linspace` includes both endpoint, so this `np.linspace(0.60,0.69,10)` will produce

```
array([ 0.6 ,  0.61,  0.62,  0.63,  0.64,  0.65,  0.66,  0.67,  0.68,  0.69])
```