# If else statements in numpy arange

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement

Basicaly I want to compare a variable between two `np.arange()`

```
x = 22.03
first = np.arange(18.5, 24.99, 0.01)
second = np.arange(25.0, 29.99, 0.01)

if x in first:
    print("x is in first")
elif x in second:
    print("x is in second")
```

I expect to see "x isin first" but rather I get nothing printed on the terminal.
If I add another `else:` statement it will execute whatever is in that.

I am using numpy because I want to have a range of floats. The native `range()` function doesn't support floats

There happens no comparison between the two, why is that?

Comment: please, refer to ["In" operator for numpy arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452843/in-operator-for-numpy-arrays)

Comment: Did you see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42999216/3281097) in another thread? It suggest using `np.linspace` instead of `np.arange` when using small non-integer steps as in your case

Comment: `if np.isclose(first, x).any(): print("x is in first")`

Comment: The problem is that `22.03` cannot be represented exactly in binary.  It's an infinitely repeating "decimal", so what you get is an approximation.   The same applies to `0.01`.  `18.5` can be represented exactly, but as you add the increment one by one, you accumulate more and more rounding errors.  So, you get to something close to `22.03`, but not as close as the constant `22.03`.  That's why `isclose` is a better option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your array:

```
In [254]: first = np.arange(18.5, 24.99, 0.01)
In [255]: first.shape
Out[255]: (649,)
In [256]: first[:10]
Out[256]: 
array([18.5 , 18.51, 18.52, 18.53, 18.54, 18.55, 18.56, 18.57, 18.58,
       18.59])
In [257]: x=22.03
```

`x` isn't "found"

```
In [258]: x in first
Out[258]: False
```

Let's look for a close match:

```
In [259]: np.nonzero(np.isclose(x,first))
Out[259]: (array([353]),)
In [260]: first[353]
Out[260]: 22.030000000000552
```

The closest match is still a bit off - due to floating point calculations.  'in/equal' tests on floating point values are not reliable.

`arange` recommends `linspace` when using float steps.  The resulting values are a closer match to our expectations:

```
In [264]: first1 = np.linspace(18.5,24.98,len(first))
In [265]: np.nonzero(np.isclose(x,first1))
Out[265]: (array([353]),)
In [266]: first1[353]
Out[266]: 22.03
In [267]: x in first1
Out[267]: True
```

There still is a potential for a float mismatch.

To better see the full precision of the floats, lets display the arrays as lists

```
In [268]: first[:10].tolist()
Out[268]: 
[18.5,
 18.51,
 18.520000000000003,
 18.530000000000005,
 18.540000000000006,
 18.550000000000008,
 18.56000000000001,
 18.57000000000001,
 18.580000000000013,
 18.590000000000014]
In [269]: first1[:10].tolist()
Out[269]: [18.5, 18.51, 18.52, 18.53, 18.54, 18.55, 18.56, 18.57, 18.58, 18.59]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 22.03
first = np.arange(18.5, 24.99, 0.01)
second = np.arange(25.0, 29.99, 0.01)

type(first)
Out[13]: numpy.ndarray

# cast to list and proper value rounding for boolean comparison
first = [round(n, 2) for n in first]

x in first
Out[16]: True
```

Comment: Although this seems to solve the problem at hand, that's just an accident.  `round` is a dangerous function for floating point values.  The result is STILL an approximation, and you have lost potential information.  As a general rule, you should keep your data with its natural precision until the point where you need to show it to a human, and only then do the rounding.

Comment: you're correct Tim