# np.arange producing elements with many decimals

Tags: python, numpy, loops

I have the following loop.

```
x_array = []

for x in np.arange(0.01, 0.1, 0.01 ):
    
    x_array.append(x)
```

Why are some of the elements in x_array in so many decimals?

```
[0.01,
 0.02,
 0.03,
 0.04,
 0.05,
 0.060000000000000005,
 0.06999999999999999,
 0.08,
 0.09]
```

Comment: did you see the note in the docs about fractional steps?

Comment: See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71071089/if-else-statements-in-numpy-arange

Answer (score 1):

If you want your list of numbers without "additional" digits in the
fractional part, try the following code:

```
x_array = np.arange(0.01, 0.1, 0.01).round(2).tolist()
```

As you see, you don't even need any explicit loop.

The result is just what you want, i.e.:

```
[0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09]
```

Another choice is:

```
x_array = (np.arange(1, 10) / 100).tolist()
```